# $\sum a_n<\infty$ $\iff$ $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}<\infty$, $(a_n)>0$

Tags: real-analysis

I will first start by proving the left-to-right implication.

> Since $a_n>0$ we have that $b_n:=\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}>0$, so we are studying series of non-negative terms, thus we can apply all the different criterions we know (specially the [Direct Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test)) to study the convergence of $\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}$.
>
> Now, since $$\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}\leq a_n$$
> we have $$\sum \frac{a_n}{1+na_n}\leq \sum a_n<\infty$$
> Where the notation $<\infty$ means that the series is convergent.

I haven't been able to prove the other implication, I start to suspect that it is false, but I also didn't manage to generate a counter-example. Can anyone please help me find it?

Comment: It gives me a hint, saying that I should use a lacunar series to prove the other implication.

Comment: Where did you read this exercice ? The reverse implication is false.